# How to use the conv1d_transpose in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, convolution, conv-neural-network

The `conv1d_transpose` is not yet in the stable version of Tensorflow, but an implementation is available [on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/13105/files/7c3b105d618fe90cf3f580a141d41e9d4ba76bb3)

I would like to create a 1D deconvolution network. The shape of the input is `[-1, 256, 16]` and the output should be `[-1,1024,8]`. The kernel's size is 5 and the stride is 4.

I tried to build a 1D convolutional layer with this function:

```
    (output_depth, input_depth) = (8, 16)
    kernel_width = 7
    f_shape = [kernel_width, output_depth, input_depth]
    layer_1_filter = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(f_shape))

    layer_1 = tf_exp.conv1d_transpose(
        x,
        layer_1_filter,
        [-1,1024,8],
        stride=4, padding="VALID"
    )
```

The shape of `layer_1` is `TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(None)])`, but it should be `[-1,1024,8]`

What do I wrong? How is it possible to implement 1D deconvolution in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new *[tf.contrib.nn.conv1d_transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/nn/conv1d_transpose)* is now added to [Tensorflow API r1.8](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/).

Answer (score 3):

The pull request is open as of this moment, so the API and behavior can and probably will change. Some feature that one might expect from `conv1d_transpose` aren't supported:

- `output_shape` requires batch size to be known statically, can't pass `-1`;
- on the other hand, output shape is dynamic (this explains `None` dimension).

Also, the `kernel_width=7` expects `in_width=255`, not `256`. Should make `kernel_width` less than `4` to match `in_width=256`. The result is this demo code:

```
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 256, 16], dtype=tf.float32)
filter = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 8, 16]))    # [kernel_width, output_depth, input_depth]
out = conv1d_transpose(x, filter, output_shape=[100, 1024, 8], stride=4, padding="VALID")

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  result = sess.run(out, feed_dict={x: np.zeros([100, 256, 16])})
  print(result.shape)  # prints (100, 1024, 8)
```