# TensorFlow conv1d_transpose Filter Values

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

The `conv1d_transpose` in `tf.contrib.nn` needs to take a '*filter*' as a parameter. Unlike the transposed convolution functions for other dimensions this function doesn't automatically create a tensor from a list so it seems to require the user to create a filter as a tensor.

I therefore can't create a filter with a list such as `[filter_width, output_channels, input_channels]` but instead need to create the tensor and then pass that to '*filter*'.  But I don't know what values I need to set when I create the Tensor.

I have seen on an answer to another question ([How to use the conv1d_transpose in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47106331/how-to-use-the-conv1d-transpose-in-tensorflow)) that it may be created as below:

```
tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([filter_width, output_channels, input_channels])
```

I want to know is this the standard way to create the transposed filter?  That is, with `tf.random_normal`. Specifically, does this match how the conv2d_transpose function creates the transposed filter? (I've looked through the documentation and code on GitHub but can't find where this should be occurring).